# The complete residue systems modulo $p$ from reduce residue system modulo $n$

Tags: number-theory

Let $p$ be a prime divisor of $n$ and $1=a_1<a_2<\dots<a_{\varphi(n)}<n$ be a reduce congruent system of $n$. When $\{a_1,\dots,a_{p-1}\},\{a_p,\dots,a_{2p-1}\},\dots$ are complete congruent system modulo $p$?

Comment: They are never as a complete residue system modulo $p$ must include an element divisible by $p$, which therefore is not co-prime with $n$ and cannot be contained in a reduced residue system modulo $n$.

Comment: $\{a_1,\dots,a_{p-1}\}\cup\{0\}$ is complete congruent system modulo $p$.